# JavaScript onKeypress validation

Tags: javascript, validation, event-handling

This is a function for JavaScript validation:

```
var alpha = "[ A-Za-z]";
var numeric = "[0-9]"; 
var alphanumeric = "[ A-Za-z0-9]"; 

function onKeyValidate(e,charVal){
    var keynum;
    var keyChars = /[\x00\x08]/;
    var validChars = new RegExp(charVal);
    if(window.event)
    {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if(e.which)
    {
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    if (!validChars.test(keychar) && !keyChars.test(keychar))   {
        return false
    } else{
        return keychar;
    }
}
```

and HTML code:

```
<input type="text"  name="shipname"  onkeypress="return onKeyValidate(event,alpha);"/>
<input type="text"  name="price"   onkeypress="return onKeyValidate(event,numeric);" />
```

I want to know about code quality, creating issues or any alternative for this.  I need some suggestion from experts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `onKeyValidate` is an okay name, but a better name could be `validateKeypress`.
- It seems very silly to store a RegExp as a string, and then construct it every time. Why not just declare `var alpha = /[ A-Za-z]/`?
- `keyChars` appears to check against `\x00`, the null character, and `\x08`, the backspace character. Neither of these can ever be passed to `onKeypress`, so you can just take it out.
- The standard way to get the character code is `event.which || event.keyCode`.
- `event` is a global; I don't think you need to pass it in.

Here's a proposed rewrite:

```
var alpha = /[ A-Za-z]/;
var numeric = /[0-9]/; 
var alphanumeric = /[ A-Za-z0-9]/;

function validateKeypress(validChars) {
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode);
    return validChars.test(keyChar) ? keyChar : false;
}
```

The HTML will have to change to `onkeypress="validateKeypress(alpha);"`.

Comment: This is not working for me. onkeyPress="return validateKeypress(event,alphanumeric);" and javascript : function validateKeypress(e,validChars)
{
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
    return validChars.test(keyChar) ? keyChar : false;
} This only working for me

Answer (score 1):

The thing that I was able to pick out, and it's more of a nitpick type of things is that you should turn your last if statement around

```
if (!validChars.test(keychar) && !keyChars.test(keychar))   {
    return false
} else{
    return keychar;
}
```

should look like this

```
if (validChars.test(keychar) && keyChars.test(keychar)) {
    return keychar;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Do your Positive first.  most people like this better than all the negatives.

*Side Note*: for code golfing you just shaved 2 characters as well as made it more standard compliant if this nitpick can be considered a standard.

***Short Version***:

If you know Ternary operators and would like to use them instead of this simple if statement, @renatargh mentioned that you could make this super short

```
return validChars.test(keychar) && keyChars.test(keychar) ? keychar : false;
```

---

Also,  `var alphanumeric = "[ A-Za-z0-9]";` is never used (in this code block) and neither is 
`var keyChars = /[\x00\x08]/;`

you should just get rid of them

Comment: he can even reduce it to; `return validChars.test(keychar) && keyChars.test(keychar) ? keychar : false;`

Comment: I want to use backspace tab and tab key. How is it possible without /[\x00\x08]/ ?